# Test a microphone with an intermittent fault

Tags: windows-xp, microphone

I have a microphone with all the software set up correctly, but there is a loose connection somewhere. I'd like some software to give me instant feedback on whether the computer is picking up the sound of my voice so that I can wiggle some wires and work out where the fault is. Any suggestions?

Comment: by feedback, do you mean specifically audio feedback? Or are you able to monitor the screen whilst wiggling wires?

Comment: either audio or visual will do... as long as its instant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could probably use [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) - it has both an audio level meter and a graph

Answer (score 2):

The Volume Control panel shows a monitor for input devices. I think they added it in one of the Service Packs. If you play a constant tone and put the microphone in front of the speaker, you can use the monitor to see when it works/dies.

Comment: @echoback: I can't see a "monitor" on the volume control panel.